# Can WordPress be installed at the root level, if a homepage called index.php already exists?

Tags: installation, mod-rewrite

Can WordPress be installed at the root level, if a homepage called index.php already exists?

Comment: Question is offtopic, please ask at [WordPress Q&A](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)

Comment: In addition to Sathya's comment, include why you want to do that.

Comment: Per Rarst comment below, don't forget about the change when you upgrade if you proceed -- because WP will nuke your file.

Answer (score 4):

In theory, you could rename the file and change the rewrite rule accordingly. Assuming you rename it to wp-index.php, it would look something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp-index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

There are a few references to index.php in the WP source, but they're almost all either in the admin area and used to detect or direct to the dashboard, or explicitly for servers that don't fully support mod_rewrite.

Comment: Possible, but I think first WordPress update will nuke foreign `index.php`.

Comment: Very true, but I'll make the assumption that the question's author realizes. :-)

Comment: Make index.php read-only. Disable auto-update. (Always test this first).

Answer (score 2):

No, `index.php` file is present and used in WordPress ([source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.3/index.php)).

Depending on what existing *homepage* is it can be renamed to another non-conflicting file or migrated to WordPress.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would it take to do that? Is it just a matter of .htaccess changes, or are there core hacks necessary as well?

Comment: You mean renaming? I meant that changing old `index.php` to `some-other-name.php` so it is moved to `domain.com/some-other-name.php` and does not intersect with WordPress.

Comment: You can do this in .htaccess or with a filter in your functions.php though it is really a bad idea, so I not going to post it.